# How To Dynamically Create ViewFlow Processes?

Tags: django-viewflow

I'm trying to set up a service so that a user could feasibly build their own workflows through a GUI or otherwise easy-to-use interface.

When I try anonymously creating nodes and then referring to them by their position in a list, I get stuck - `this.nodes[0]` (where `nodes` is the list storing the anonymous nodes) fails because "this" isn't iterable, `this.(nodes[0])` is invalid syntax, and `nodes[0]` (sans `this`) returns a `NoneType` object.

How can I go about dynamically generating nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in the Viewflow.